# Flutter/Dart: Regex Replace with $2?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, replaceall

I'm trying to grab just the id number from a Facebook picture URL using the replaceall regex method in Dart. What should I be using instead of $2 in the following code? The id number I need is between the "asid=" and "&height".

```
void main() {
 String faceavatar = 'https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=10153806530149154&height=50&width=50&ext=1596623207&hash=AeSi1yDvk8TCqZql';
      String currentavatar = faceavatar.replaceAll(RegExp('(.*asid=)(\d*)height.*'), $2;
  print(currentavatar);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try:

```
.*?\basid\b=(\d+).*
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`.*?`** - **Lazily** matches everything except new-line before `asid`.
- **`\basid\b`** - Matches `asid` literally. `\b` represents word boundary.
- **`=`** - Matches `=` literally.
- **`(\d+)`** - Represents first capturing group matching digits one or more times.
- **`.*`** - **Greedily** everything except new-line zero or more times.
- **`$1`** - For the replacement part you can use `$1` or `match.group(1)`.

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

You can find the demo of above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/wK9MQ1/14)

**Sample Implementation in dart:**

```
void main() {
 String faceavatar = 'https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=10153806530149154&height=50&width=50&ext=1596623207&hash=AeSi1yDvk8TCqZql';
      String currentavatar = faceavatar.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'.*?\basid\b=(\d+).*'), (match) {
  return '${match.group(1)}';
});
  print(currentavatar);
}
```

You can find the sample run of the above implementation in [**here.**](https://tio.run/##VdDBToNAEAbge59iD6YsVYEtBVvNpmnUoxfryXBZYGE3BXa7DIhpeHYEYmqc0@SfSebLpMzAMLRKpqhkssI2uizQEYyscpSxhLOWATOIIksA6PrRdXXBIFOmvC@UOrFaptzJ4jrunESV16GrjcpkwbVM3P20RIlHAn/rhYHvkc2OBJul4DIXQANv@SVTEFPDO6Ak2IXh2l97D0vBakEP/CjJ90t72n48nz/PhfW0QHP9KpPGGF7BFfqndgwfPQk/FMUb05qn@J3nr53GxnJW@yieXFFMcZTe2s7Ksu8QLhkkYv4BMhwaUyHr5jKHTm5UozGx@xHQ2xNCj/cB/7s/5v0w/AA)

Answer (score -1):

just getting the asid:

`(?<=(asid=))(\w|\d|\n|[().,\-:;@#$%^&*\[\]"'+–/\/®°⁰!?{}|]| )+?(?=(&height))`

output: 10153806530149154